# SFSafariController loads URL fine in simulator but leaves a blank screen on device

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, ios10, is-empty, sfsafariviewcontroller

So I'm using SFSafariController to load up an URL downloaded from cloudkit, like so.

```
    if let yelpurl = detail.value(forKey: "Yelp") as? String
    {

        let url = URL(string:  (yelpurl))
        let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: url!, entersReaderIfAvailable: false)
        safari.delegate = self as? SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
        self.present(safari, animated: true, completion: {

        })
    } else {
    }

}
```

The code itself is fine - no errors, pulls up the yelp page URL and loads it up in an SFSafariController in simulator, but on my device, I am left with a white blank screen. What is causing this disparity and how can I correct this on device?

To add, the plist still stands without any modification.

Edit 1:
I created a new project to purely test the below mentioned code to possibly discover a new error.  This is what I found - and wondering how to solve.
[image]

Update:
I updated to 10.3.3 and deleted my browsing history.

Comment: Problem with any link or just with your website only? Try to open https://google.com

Comment: Even https://google.com does not work on device.

Comment: The URL is taken from a variable received from cloud kit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just created a sample project and it works on both simulator and iPhone 6S iOS 10.3.2, code:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
            self.showLinksClicked()
        }

    }

    func showLinksClicked() {

        let yelpurl = "https://google.com"
        let url = URL(string:  (yelpurl))
        let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: url!, entersReaderIfAvailable: false)
        safari.delegate = self as? SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
        self.present(safari, animated: true, completion: {
        })
    }
}
```

So looks like something is wrong with your URL or with way you call the method to present safari. Put your code to a separate method and be sure that you pass right URL.

Comment: Did you add any info to your plist?

Comment: @jonpeter no, just create new single-view app and replace ViewController.swift code by provided in my reply. No other additional magic. Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: @jonpeter in your code just call "self.showLinksClicked()" in the place you need to show this website - button tap event, any handler or where ever you need it.

Comment: unfortunately, your solution worked once and the issue has returned.

Comment: @jonpeter to restart the app just tap Home button twice (home button - the only hardware button on the front side of iPhone) and then swipe app process up. Then open app once again and enjoy that it's working)) The main reason of this behaviour that my app is one-time app to show you that solution works and I call presenting safari on viewDidLoad method. Feel free to move it to viewWillAppear for example to see it more often or to create a button and call safari every time you tap the button.

Answer (score 1):

On my app I did this:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        }

    }

    func linkIsClicked(){

       let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: "your url")! as URL)
        self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        safariVC.delegate = self
}
```

And it perfectly works

Comment: Any changes to your plist?